# REPL on console emacs

Tags: emacs, lisp, read-eval-print-loop

I'm using the console version of emacs (that is, I'm SSH'ed into a remote machine and using emacs there) and I was wondering how (assuming it's possible) to start up the REPL from there. I'm pretty new to Lisp and emacs.

Comment: You can run Emacs Lispspongor and

Answer (score 31, accepted):

How about `M-x ielm`?

ielm: Inferior Emacs Lisp Mode

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but what flavor of Lisp am I running when I'm here?

Comment: Ah, that's logical. And I'm trying to Google this without success: how do I leave ielm?

Comment: `C-d` at an empty prompt kills the REPL.  Try `M-x describe-mode` (usually bound to `C-h m`) to see all the key-bindings.

Answer (score 3):

You can run a terminal emulator with `M-x term` in Emacs and use any REPL you like in there.  I prefer it to inferior modes, but I think it's just a matter of taste.

Comment: I was wondering which REPL to run in terminal emulator for elisp?