# REPL for Emacs Lisp

Tags: emacs, elisp, read-eval-print-loop

What are some REPLs for Emacs Lisp?

Is there only one that is within Emacs?

Are there some that run inside terminal outside Emacs?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Based on this question: [REPL on console emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250913/repl-on-console-emacs), you can use `M-x ielm` (inferior emacs lisp mode).

Comment: Thanks! Must that run within emacs, or can it run in bash outside emacs? I tried `ieml` or `ielm` in bash, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think it can be run outside of Emacs, but I could be wrong.

Comment: 'ielm' is a lisp program. It runs only inside emacs.  If you want to try things in a terminal, you can use `emacs --batch

Comment: The term "REPL" stands for "read-eval-print-loop" which originally comes from Lisp, which literally has functions named `read`, `eval`, and `print`.  Emacs Lisp is no different, so you can do `emacs --batch --eval '(while t (print (eval (read))))'` to get what you want.

Comment: I tend to forget its name, so I made an "alias" for it: `(defun repl() (interactive) (ielm))`. Then you can launch the interpreter with `M-x repl`.

Comment: @Jabba You can also say: `(defalias 'repl 'ielm)`

Answer (score 3):

There is a (work in progress) REPL for Emacs for use from the command line. It currently supports basic command line editing and history.

The code is [hosted on Github](https://github.com/tetracat/emacsrepl).

Answer (score 2):

There is [this project](https://gitlab.com/jpellegrini/eltr) on Gitlab. The REPL can run on a termninal or on Emacs' minibuffer. Even if you run it in "no-window-system" mode (with `-nw`).

Answer (score 1):

One can also just run eshell

```
M-x eshell
```

example

```
~/.emacs.d/org $ (directory-files "." nil ".org") 
("#x1.org#" "#x2.org#" ".#x3.org" ...
```